# EF 4.1 and two-level object inserts fail

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am trying to create a complex structure in my database.  My table structure is:

```
Parent
  ID

Hier
  ID
  ParentHierID
  Desc

Child
  ID
  ParentID
  HierID

Sibling
  ID
  ChildID
  SiblingTypeID

SiblingType
  ID
  Desc
```

Here's what I'm doing:

```
 _objectSet = _context.CreateObjectSet<Parent>();
Parent p = Mapper.Map(ParentView, Parent>(parentView);
Child c;
Sibling s;

foreach ( var hier in TopLevels)
{
    c = new Child();
    c.HierId = hier.ID;
    ..set some other fields from foo...
    p.Childs.Add(c);
    s = new Sibling();
    s.SiblingTypeID = 1;
    c.Siblings.Add(s);
}
_objectSet.AddObject(p);  
_context.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.None);
```

This results in an exception:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
"Sibling_Child_FK". The conflict occurred in database "DB", 
table "Child", column 'ID'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

If I don't create the Sibling, and remove `c.Siblings.Add(s);` then everything works.  (Note that there is a trigger on the Child table that inserts the rest of the hierarchy from the Hier table).

Should EF4.1 be able to handle inserting multiple levels of objects like this?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else runs into this, the problem is because of the trigger.

Eliminating the trigger eliminated the problem, and I can create 3-4 levels deep and save it without any issues.